# spring data elasticsearch Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: spring-java-config, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have problem with Spring Data Elasticsearch. I configure elasticsearch like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.project.repositories"})
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org.project.repositorieselastic")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContext {
@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}

@Bean
public Client client(){

    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
        // Setting "transport.type" enables this module:
        .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
        .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", false)
        .build();


    TransportClient client= new TransportClient(settings);
    TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300);
    client.addTransportAddress(address);
    return client;
}
```

}

My repo looks like.

```
@Repository()
public interface UserFavoriteElasticRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<UserFavorite, Long> {
```

}

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.project.repositorieselastic.UserFavoriteElasticRepo org.project.services.elastic.FavoriteIndexerService.elasticRepo; nested exception
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userFavoriteElasticRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

It's look like the implementation is not generated. But I don't know where to investigate. I tried to use one package and use this - https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/commit/874ccba09189d6ef897bc430c43b6e3705404399 but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem adding this in pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got same exception using spring-data-elasticsearch.
But exception was thrown when I declared new methods in repository:
ex.:

```
public interface UserFavoriteElasticRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<UserFavorite, Long> {
Page<UserFavorite> findBySomeProperty(String propertyValue, Pageable pageable);
```

}

It was casued due to spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-data-commons versions. Function declarations have changed:  org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery - it caused the exception.
For spring-data-elasticsearch version 2.0.0.RELEASE you have to use spring-data-commons with version 1.12.0.
If you have spring-data-jpa in your project it also uses spring-data-commons. For spring-data-jpa v1.9.0.RELEASE, spring-data-commons is v1.11.0.RELEASE

Could you provide what frameworks and versions of spring you are using? Also If you could put whole stacktrace, it will be helpfull?